# Combining multiple Objects in ReactJS export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-maps-react

So I have a React component that uses the `google-maps-react` package along with `redux`

Now the thing is that I need to export `connect()` and the `GoogleApiWrapper` together.
I googled a bit and found someone who did it like this :

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { saveMapCoords }
)(
  GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyA5EqRGJ-YR-2ZCGxThhtFZKwNBy6wk73c'
  })
)(Maps)
```

Where `Maps` is the class name.

Unfortunately I get this error : 
`TypeError: Object(...)(...)(...) is not a function`

This is returned from the line `GoogleApiWrapper`

Does anyone know why this happens? They work separately but not together

Comment: It seems you are misplacing one bracket:
`
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { saveMapCoords }
)(
  GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyA5EqRGJ-YR-2ZCGxThhtFZKwNBy6wk73c'
  })
)(Maps))
`

Comment: This is actually the same as I wrote above but with an extra bracket at the end, and the bracket at the end gives me a compiling error that says that there is a bracket that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing a bracket before. The `GoogleApiWrapper`

```
GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY_GOES_HERE)
})(MapContainer)
```

is a HOC that'll return a new component that you'll then pass in the `connect`.

Try this

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { saveMapCoords }
)(
    GoogleApiWrapper({
        apiKey: "AIzaSyA5EqRGJ-YR-2ZCGxThhtFZKwNBy6wk73c"
    })(Maps)
)
```

Comment: Oh I see, so I wasn't that far away from what I wanted. Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: Glad it helped :)